# Android phone is disconnected when adb is started

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to debug the android phone with adb tool. When I run the adb command on the command prompt, the connected phone get disconnected from the system. I want to use adb logcat on the phone. I am using following command:

```
adb -s <device_id> logcat
```

After entering the command on command line, it says: `adb server out of date. Killing...` and after that phone gets disconnected and command line shows `waiting for device...`

Any idea how to solve the problem? I just want to run logcat on the android device. I am using HTC Wildfire phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated the Phone software, and now using `adb logcat` command in place of `adb -s<decive_id> logcat` command.

It just worked fine for me.